# Weird movie/tv episode where chess game was played with human heads

Tags: story-identification, movie, hard-sci-fi, episode-identification

It was futuristic and the chess pieces had personalities. They talked and when they took another piece they would murder them in some way. The player of the player of the game had to turn silver knobs to move the pieces. I remember it being slightly funny too and with a lot of gore.

Comment: Do you remember anything else about the show? What was it about? Were they in space? Were they humans? Was it animated? Approximately when was it made?

Comment: So the chess pieces had human heads stuck on them? Or was it implied that there were humans embedded in the pieces? Or they were mechanical?

Answer (score 7):

Could this be [Lexx: The Game](http://lexx.wikia.com/wiki/The_Game)?

> Kai wins, but *seemingly* gains nothing

Comment: I can't understand why this site doesn't get more questions about *Lexx*.

Comment: Funny how these fictional chess games never end in a draw.

Comment: @user14111 - Lexx was more plot-hole than plot, that's why.